# Create a test enviroment in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have a production enviroment in a Oracle 10g database which I would like to authomatically duplicate in a test enviroment. My production enviroment is just a number of tables in which I have usually indices, constrains and triggers.
Is there a way to authomatically make a copy of the prod-enviroment including all tables, indices, triggers and constrains without the data in the tables?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Look into the `DataPump` utility

Comment: you probably can replicate it, but notice that the idea of keeping prod and dev is to have some isolation from one another for security reasons (so your dev code won't affect your prod system).

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the expdp CONTENT flag:

```
expdp username/password DIRECTORY=directory_object_name \
                        DUMPFILE=dumpfile_name \
                        TABLES=table_names|TABLESPACES=tablespace_names|FULL=y \
                        CONTENT=metadata_only
```

Answer (score 0):

mmmmmpie offers you a very viable way to do it. However, especially if you want to get your test environment as close to possible as prod for testing purposes, I highly recommend you look into RMAN cloning. You will end up with a block-for-block recreation of your production environment, which IMO is worth its weight in gold in regard to performance tuning (assuming the underlying tech stack is similar).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/rcmdupdb.htm

There's a 10g version of the methodology. HTH.